# C# How to have an object available in another method?

Tags: c#, object, methods

I have two methods, in the ConnecttoDB method I create an object called connection, but i need that object in the second method to specify the SQLiteCommand. How can I have it, that the object is available in the InsertField Method ?

```
public class Database
{
    private static string _datasource;
    private static string _table;
    private static string _field;
    private static string _values;

    public static void ConnecttoDB(string datasource)
    {
        _datasource = datasource;
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source: " + _datasource;
        connection.Open();
    }
    public static void InsertField(string table, string field, string values)
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(/*connection*/);

        _table = table;
        _field = field;
        _values = values;
        String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} {1} VALUES{2}", _table, _field, _values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to expose the object in some way. Either make it a property/field of the class or pass it into the method. I would recommend using some kind of ORM rather than rolling your own data access.

Comment: Why do you have a static field for the string representation at all? You could make that a SQLiteConnection field instead. I personally wouldn't use this design to start with, but that's a different method. (I wouldn't have static variables for field/table/values, and I wouldn't use string formatting to embed the values in SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead!)

Comment: In this particular case you shouldn't actually *have* two methods.  Creating the database connection object should happen in the method that uses it, and it should be done inside a `using` block so that it's disposed when the operation is completed.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Good point. Also, I dont think its a good idea to make the ConnecttoDB static and leave it open. IMO, especially in a web environment, each Database event should have an open and close event to prevent leaving the db connection open.

Comment: @David Could you be so kind and give a code example ?

Comment: If you want to make it static then declare the class as static as well. `public static class Database { ... }`

Comment: @PhilVallone: Absolutely - although I probably wouldn't use SQLite in a web environment in the first place :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet It is not a web enviroment, it is used for an offline database.

Comment: @user2684089: Right. I'd still go with the "open and close as required" model anyway though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class design is very odd. Why do you declare `_table`, `_field` and `_values` as class fields for no apparent reason, but don't do it for `connection`, which would solve your problem? You can use the `table`, `field` and `values` parameters directly, without assigning them to fields beforehand.

Let me suggest another approach:

```
public class Database
{
    private string _connectionString;

    // Pass the datasource through the constructor.
    public Database(string datasource)
    {
        _connectionString = "Data Source: " + datasource;
    }

    public void InsertField(string table, string field, object value)
    {
        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString)) {
            string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES (@1)",
                                       table, field);
            var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", value);
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

*(Not tested, calling conventions might be different for SQLite)*

I am using the `object` type for `value` which is compatible with any type. Also I am passing this value to the command as command-parameter. Like this, `DateTime` values, for instance, are automatically converted to the right format for SQLite. It also prevents [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). (I hope that the table and field names are defined by the application and not entered by the user so.)

Because of the connection pooling, the system maintains connections open a while and reuses open connections automatically. Therefore the `connection.Open();` call does not really reopen the connection physically every time it is called. On the other hand, this approach prevents connections to be open a very long time and using system resources without being used.

The `using` statement takes automatically care of closing the connection and disposing the resources used by the connection - even when an exception should occur before the code block reaches its end.

You can use it like this:

```
var db = new Database("my data source");
db.InsertField("myTable", "myField", 100);
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need a variable number of parameters, I would use arrays for the fields and values:

```
public void InsertField(string table, string[] fields, object[] values)
{
    if (fields.Length != values.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "The fields and values arrays must have the same length");
    }

    string fieldNames = String.Join(", ", fields); // ==> "name1, name2, name3"

    // ==> "@p0, @p1, @p2"
    string paramNames = String.Join(", ",
        Enumerable.Range(0, fields.Length)
            .Select(i => "@p" + i)
            .ToArray()
    );
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString)) {
        string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
                                   table, fieldNames, paramNames);
        var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + i, values[i]);
        }
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var db = new Database("my data source");
db.InsertField("myTable", 
               new string[]{ "Name", "Quantity", "Price", "Date" }, 
               new object[]{ "Apples", 12, 2.65m, DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: Im very new to programming in general, sometimes i dont understand simple concepts. I didn't know that i could have an object as an class field. Thank you!

Comment: I do have a problem, which I hope you could help me with. It works fine as long as I only want to add 1 Value at a given time, but if I try to insert multiple values, I get a error message "1 values for 2 columns". I ran it with this line db.InsertField("Item", "Name, Category","Apple,Grocery"); How do I seperate the Values?

Comment: Also tried db.InsertField("Item", "Name, Category","'Apple','Grocery'");

Comment: I'm really confused right now... I tried db.InsertField("Item", "Name, Category","'Apple','Grocery'"); and it wont work, but if I change the object to a string it works...

Comment: I added an example of how you could solve the problem of a variable number of fields.

Answer (score 2):

**To address the issue you're currently facing:**

In this case you shouldn't actually be doing that.  Your two methods should be one method:

```
public static void InsertField(string table, string field, string values)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection())
    {
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
        {
            _table = table;
            _field = field;
            _values = values;
            String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} {1} VALUES{2}", _table, _field, _values);
            // and the rest of the code, incomplete in the example
        }
    }
}
```

Building a SQL connection object isn't an expensive process.  And it's only a single line of code.  So you're not actually saving much by offloading it to another method.  What you *are* doing, however, is introducing a number of other potential runtime problems (as opposed to the easily-visible compile-time problem you currently have), such as resource leaks and disposed object errors.

Encapsulate the connection and command objects as close to their usage as possible, and dispose of them as soon as possible when you're done with them.  The underlying system is very well optimized to re-create them when you need them again in another method (or the same method called again).

**To address your question on a more literal level:**

Consider the scope of the variable being passed from one method to another, the scopes of the methods, etc.  You have options.

Is the variable an attribute of the object in which the methods exist?  For example, in a `Person` object you might have something called a `Height`.  Since that describes the person, it can be class-level:

```
public int Height { get; private set; }

public void OneMethod(int someValue)
{
    // more code
    Height = someValue;
    // more code
}

public void AnotherMethod()
{
    // more code
    someOtherObject.DoSomethingWithHeight(Height);
    // more code
}
```

If the value doesn't actually describe the object but is instead in some smaller scope, consider passing it to the method.  Maybe something like:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // more code
    var someValue = 123;
    // more code
    AHelperMethod(someValue);
    // more code
}

private void AHelperMethod(int aValue)
{
    // more code
    someOtherObject.DoSomethingWithValue(aValue);
    // more code
}
```

In the first case both methods were enacting some action on the object itself, using an attribute which describes that object.  In the second case the second method is just something internal to the object and is only there to support the first method's higher-level action.  It *could* just be inline code in the first method, but it's been extracted into its own method for reuse, readability, maintaining levels of abstraction, or any number of refactoring reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Have the connection as a private instance field, it can then be used in all methods. Also remove static keywords. Static is rarely needed and is usually bad.

```
public class Database
{
    private string _datasource;
    private string _table;
    private string _field;
    private string _values;
    private SQLiteConnection _connection;

    public void ConnecttoDB(string datasource)
    {
        _datasource = datasource;
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection();
        _connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source: " + _datasource;
        _connection.Open();
    }
    public void InsertField(string table, string field, string values)
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(_connection);

        _table = table;
        _field = field;
        _values = values;
        String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} {1} VALUES{2}", _table, _field, _values);
    }
}
```

Comment: quite clearly the class is incomplete. I am not fixing every issue with the code - or completing it - I am answering the specific question of how to make that info available to another method.

Comment: So... Solving a problem by creating a more difficult problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either you keep it global or pass it as an argument to InsertFields. In the latter case You must create it somewhere and then pass to Your method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to declare the SQLiteConnection object as a class level variable. Then your InsertField method would then use the class level variable like so:

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);

Comment: @David Agreed! I personally wouldn't have went the route he did. That's why I mentioned the "easiest"...not the best :)